# ESS indentation of parentheses after =?

Tags: indentation, ess, r

Indentation in ESS is occasionally a little kooky, and I'm trying to figure out if the kookiness is a bug or a feature.  How does one get proper indentation of parentheses after an "=" sign in ESS (say, in `R-mode`)?

As an example, I'd expect indentation to look like this for the "labels" parameter:

```
somevar <- factor(x = 1:3,
                  labels = c("a",
                             "b",
                             "c"))
```

Instead, I get:

```
somevar <- factor(x = 1:3,
                  labels = c("a",
                    "b",
                    "c"))
```

This version (note the extra parentheses wrapped around the `c(...)` expression) seems to work just fine, however:

```
somevar <- factor(x = 1:3,
                  labels = (c("a",
                              "b",
                              "c")))
```

This oddity only seems to occur if it's after the "=".  How do I get the desired behavior?  Am I missing some setting somewhere?  (I hope so: wading through the source code for `ess-indent-line` is not an explosion of joy.)

*NOTE:* I'd originally asked a version of 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056585/emacs-ess-indentation-of-parentheses-after) on Stack Overflow about half a year ago -- it got a little interest but zero answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `ess-arg-function-offset` to `nil`:

```
(setf ess-arg-function-offset nil)
```

For me this indents your examples the way that you want them to be. Read the documentation of the variable to find out why (and note that `c` is a function call).

Simply setting it once in an init file does not work. A simple way for it to register is to set it in `ess-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook (lambda () (setq ess-arg-function-offset nil)))
```

This is because of the way that those style variables are set from a list of possible default styles (listed in `ess-style-alist`) for each ess buffer at their creation. This hook adjusts `ess-arg-function-offset` after the fact, which is why it works when a single setting in `init.el` doesn't work. You can define your own style and give it a name, and use it instead of one of the builtin ones, similar to what you can do with CC mode.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!  Oddly enough, simply setting it once in an init file does not seem to work -- I had to set it in `ess-mode-hook` for it to register.

Comment: @Dan, this is because of the way that those style variables are set from a list of possible default styles (listed in `ess-style-alist`) for each ess buffer at their creation. Your hook adjusts `ess-arg-function-offset` after the fact, which is why it works when a single setting in `init.el` doesn't work. You can define your own style and give it a name, and use it instead of one of the builtin ones, similar to what you can do with `cc-mode`.